# IOS, objective-c rotate animation

Tags: ios, animation

need help from the animation gods.

I want to animate a the following two images so that by swipe right the red part will rotate and disappear to the right while the blue enters from the left --> like a wheel - is that even possible?? if it is how many "slices" of red and blue images do i need and can you please help with code I know I'm asking a lot :-/

P.S: to maintain copy rights I've posted the images with their original watermark.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Given the physical metaphor you're using, it's probably easiest to create a single image with both the red and blue feedback icons and rotate it directly using a CGAffine transform within an animation block like.  Given a self.view that corresponds to the image, you can just:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{    
  [self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];
}];
```

Or whatever angle works.  You can use the identity transform to rotate it back.

Comment: Hey, Thanks, could you please explain more how to use the identity transform to rotate it back?

Comment: @NGG Just exactly that.  Apply an identity transform and it will rotate back.